# redirect after authentication in zend framework 2

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am trying to implement a control to check if the password is expired whenever a user authenticates. I am using a `ListenerAggregateInterface` to listen to the `ZfcUser` event `authentication.success`.

After I perform my check I am not able to redirect the user to the change password page. How can I do that?

Looking around, usually people have a `MvcEvent` and so they can use the method `getReponse` to modify the headers and perform a 302 redirect, or they use redirect functionality available in controllers. In my case I have an `AdapterChainEvent` and I'm not in a controller.

Any hint is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is return *a* response instance; it doesn't need to be *the response* instance (although you could inject it into your listener aggregate if you register the aggregate via the service manager).

This will [stop event propagation an return the response to the controller](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Authentication/Adapter/AdapterChain.php#L55). The `ZfcUser\Controller\UserController` will [then return this](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Controller/UserController.php#L163) performing the redirect.